# jquery - check whether some orders exist in an array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a list of elements in an array,
elements contain rat, cat, dog, wolf, tiger, lion, elephant

The positions of elements can be switched by dragging them to rearrange the order.

Once the button - *"Get Order of Elements"* is clicked, it displays the order of the elements e.g. position 1 is the rat.

I would like to prompt a warning box after the prompting of orders.

I would like to check if some of the specific orders exist in the arranged element list.

For example, "tiger < lion < rat" will prompt a notice (e.g. "Specific Order Found!!") because of the order below:
cat, tiger, wolf, lion, dog, elephant, rat

They do not need to be neighbors, but if in the list tiger is in front of the lion and the lion is in front of the rat in the order, then the message will prompt.  Is there a method to verify the whole list whether the list contains specified orders?

**The codes are at below:**

```html
    <head>
    <title>The order of Sortable Element</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
        div.sortIt { width: 120px; background-color: #44c756; font-family: Verdana;
            float: left; margin: 4px; text-align: center; border: medium solid #999;
        padding: 4px; color:#eee; box-shadow:5px 5px 5px #444;}
      
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#sortableContainer').sortable();
   $('<br><br><div id=buttonDiv><button>Get Order of Elements</button></div>').appendTo('body');
   $('button').button().click(function() {
   var itemOrder = $('#sortableContainer').sortable("toArray");
   for (var i = 1; i < itemOrder.length; i++) {
    alert("Position: " + i + " ID: " + itemOrder[i-1]);
   }
            })

        });
    </script>

</head> 
<body>
 <div id="sortableContainer">
        <div id="rat" class="sortIt">rat</div>
        <div id="cat" class="sortIt">cat</div>
        <div id="dog" class="sortIt">dog</div>
        <div id="wolf" class="sortIt">wolf</div>
        <div id="tiger" class="sortIt">tiger</div>
        <div id="lion" class="sortIt">lion</div>
        <div id="elephant" class="sortIt">elephant</div>
    </div>
  <br><br><br>
  <p>The position is one based.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make this code runnable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made you a helping function that takes the animals order to check as a string with the format `"animal < animal"` ... and the animals array to check against and you can choose any animals array you want and the size of both arrays don't matter it's all dynamic so it will fit lot of uses, now I think it will be easy on you to do the rest :)

```js
let animals = ["cat", "tiger", "wolf", "lion", "dog", "elephant", "rat"];

function checkAnimalsOrder(animalsArr, orderStr) {
  // store the current index of the orderedAnimals array
  let ind = 0;
  // make an array from that string format "animal > animal" ...;
  let orderedAnimals = orderStr.split(" < ");
  // filter the animals array to get only the animal that have the same index
  // of the orderedAnimals array element
  return animalsArr.filter(function(animal, index) {
    if(animalsArr[index] === orderedAnimals[ind]) {
      ind++;
      return animal;
    }
  }).join("") === orderedAnimals.join("");
  // finally join the two arrays as a string and check for equality
}

// Testing 
console.log("checking for 'tiger < lion < rat':");
console.log(checkAnimalsOrder(animals, "tiger < lion < rat"));

console.log("checking for 'tiger < dog < rat':");
console.log(checkAnimalsOrder(animals, "tiger < dog < rat"));

console.log("checking for 'tiger < cat < rat':");
console.log(checkAnimalsOrder(animals, "tiger < cat < rat"));

// On the fly
console.log("checking for 'rat < tiger':");
console.log(checkAnimalsOrder(["rat", "elephant", "tiger"], "rat < tiger"));
```